# RealmSwift: Count number of unique words

Tags: swift, realm, nspredicate

Given the following setup:

```
class Message: Object {

    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var message: String = ""
}

class Chat: Object {

    var messages = List<Message>()
    var people = List<Person>()

    @objc dynamic var name:String = ""
    @objc dynamic var path:String = ""
}
```

Is there a more efficient way using functional programming to calculate teh number of unique words within the message variable within Message?

```
let messages = Array(chat.messages)
let wordDictionary = [String:Int]()
let peopleDictionary = [String]()

for messageObject in messages {

   let words = messageObject.message.components(separatedBy: " ")
   for word in words {
      if wordDictionary[word] != nil {
          wordDictionary[word] += 1
      }else{
         wordDictionary[word] = 0
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use enumerateSubstrings(in: Range) `.byWords` to break your sentence down into words and use reduce method to calculate its frequency. Don't forget to lowercase the words to make sure they don't count as different words:

---

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var byWords: [SubSequence] { components(separated: .byWords) }
    func components(separated options: String.EnumerationOptions)-> [SubSequence] {
        var components: [SubSequence] = []
        enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..., options: options) { _, range, _, _ in components.append(self[range]) }
        return components
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Sequence where Element: Hashable {
    var frequency: [Element: Int] { reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 } }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let sentence1 = "Given the following setup:"
let sentence2 = "Is there a more efficient way using functional programming to calculate the number of unique words within the message variable within Message"

let sentences = [sentence1, sentence2]
let frequency = sentences
    .joined(separator: "\n")
    .lowercased()
    .byWords
    .frequency

print(frequency.sorted(by: {$0.value > $1.value }))
```

---

This will print

> [(key: "the", value: 3), (key: "within", value: 2), (key: "message",
>   value: 2), (key: "following", value: 1), (key: "way", value: 1), (key:
>   "more", value: 1), (key: "to", value: 1), (key: "calculate", value:
>   1), (key: "number", value: 1), (key: "there", value: 1), (key: "a",
>   value: 1), (key: "is", value: 1), (key: "unique", value: 1), (key:
>   "setup", value: 1), (key: "using", value: 1), (key: "programming",
>   value: 1), (key: "given", value: 1), (key: "words", value: 1), (key:
>   "variable", value: 1), (key: "functional", value: 1), (key:
>   "efficient", value: 1), (key: "of", value: 1)]

Answer (score 0):

You asked for functional programming and you're using .componentsSeparatedBy(" ") so the assumption is that all the words have space between them.

Lets use the power of a .map, .flatmap and a Set, which are guaranteed to be unique elements. For example:

```
let sentence = "Every good boy does fine does" //6 total words, 5 unique
let words = sentence.components(separatedBy: " ")
let wordSet = Set(words)
print(wordSet.count)
```

output is

```
5
```

So then applying that to the question:

```
let messages = Array(chat.messages) //makes the Realm list a Swift Array
let x = messages.map { msgString -> [String] in
    let y = msgString.message.components(separatedBy: " ")
    return y
}
let uniqueWords = Set( x.flatMap { $0 } )
print(uniqueWords.count)
```

The map function will take each message in the array of messages and break it down into an array of array strings so it looks like this

```
[ [word0, word1, word2], [word3, word4, word5] ]
```

Then the flatMap maps the array of arrays into a single array of words

Finally Set takes all of the words and creates a set of unique words.